# How to create permanent WMI event consumer that displays message?

Tags: windows-10, event-log, wmi

I am trying to track the occurrence of specified Security events. I want a message to be displayed to the user whenever these events are logged in the Windows Security log. It was recommended that I use a permanent WMI event consumer/watcher to accomplish this but I have never used this before and don't understand how to implement it based on [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WmiSdk/monitoring-events#using-permanent-event-consumers).

If anyone can explain how I can do this for, as an example, [Event 1102](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/event-1102), it would be much appreciated.

Comment: This may help:  https://superuser.com/a/1385602/726810

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tutorial are off-topic for Stack Overflow. However, _[PowerShell and Events: Permanent WMI Event Subscriptions](https://learn-powershell.net/2013/08/14/powershell-and-events-permanent-wmi-event-subscriptions/)_ could help.

Comment: @JosefZ It is helpful but does not explain how to accomplish my task. It isn't clear how a specific event is tracked using a filter or how I would then use a consumer to display a message.

Answer (score 0):

You can user [ORMi](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ORMi/) to create watcher and get any new event:

```
WMIWatcher watcher = new WMIWatcher("root\\CimV2", "Select * From __InstanceCreationEvent WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_NTLogEvent' and TargetInstance.LogFile='Application'");
watcher.WMIEventArrived += Watcher_WMIEventArrived;

private static void Watcher_WMIEventArrived(object sender, WMIEventArgs e)
{
    //HANDLE EVENTS
}
```

Be sure to check out if the query returns the events you are expecting.

Comment: I'm working in a protected environment and unable to install the package.